# Android studio - ListView cart quantity buttons

Tags: android

Last step in my ordering appication is to show my items in a listview, each item has its own increase n decrease buttons. when I click on one of these buttons nothing happen.

ListViewAdapter

```
{

    private Context context;
    private int images[];
    private int services[];
    private LayoutInflater inflter;
    private Button btnIncrease, btnDecrease;
    private TextView tvQuantity,service;
    private ImageView icon;


    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int[] images, int[] services) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.services = services;
        this.inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(context));

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null);
        btnIncrease = view.findViewById(R.id.btnIncrease);
        btnDecrease = view.findViewById(R.id.btnDecrease);
        tvQuantity = view.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
        service = view.findViewById(R.id.tvServeice);
        icon = view.findViewById(R.id.serviceImage);
        service.setText(services[position]);
        icon.setImageResource(images[position]);

        btnIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int q = Integer.parseInt(tvQuantity.getText().toString());
                q += 1;
                tvQuantity.setText(q + "");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        btnDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int q = Integer.parseInt(tvQuantity.getText().toString());
                if (q > 0) {
                    q -= 1;
                    tvQuantity.setText(q + "");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });



        return view;
    }




    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int[] getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(int[] images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public int[] getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(int[] services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public LayoutInflater getInflter() {
        return inflter;
    }

    public void setInflter(LayoutInflater inflter) {
        this.inflter = inflter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

OrderActivity : onCreate -

```
{



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        items = findViewById(R.id.lvItems);


        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("LANG","");

        listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, images, services);
        items.setAdapter(listAdapter);




}
```

ListView.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/des_lay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDecrease"
        style="@style/QuantityPickerButtonStyle"
        android:text="-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvQuantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/initial_quantity_value"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnIncrease"
        style="@style/QuantityPickerButtonStyle"
        android:text="+" />

</LinearLayout>
```

everything works fine except the quantity in the textview doesn't change.

Thanks

Comment: If the calls work well and the children appear inside your application then you should put the onlclick inside the listview adabter
If you are not working as expected, create a special filter and request it by Get and Set

Comment: what should the filter contains and what its roll ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Create this Class and add the Codes To this Class:

> ListAdapter.class

```
public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int[] images, int[] services) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    this.services = services;
    this.inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(context));

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

Grab the code at the top of your class

Now add the code in your main class

The code is ready
Now call the kids through the View Holder
Place the commands as :

```
viewHolder.mButtonbtnDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      //  @Override
      //  public void onClick(View v) {.....
```